# Cannot run .exe file generated by Py2exe

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

Well, this is my code:

```
import tkinter

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

myFormats = [('.XLSX','*.xlsx')]
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Escolha uma planilha de imóveis',multiple=False,filetypes=myFormats)
if len(filename)>0:
    print("Arquivo escolhido ->",filename)

def pegar_nome_sheet(nome_arquivo):
    nome_sheet = nome_arquivo.replace(nome_arquivo[-5:len(nome_arquivo)], "")
    nome_sheet = nome_sheet.replace(nome_sheet[0:len(nome_sheet)-18], "")
    return nome_sheet

planilha = load_workbook(filename)
sheet = planilha.get_sheet_by_name(pegar_nome_sheet(filename))
refs = []

z=0
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A2':sheet.max_row]:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        refs.insert(z,cellObj.value)
        z+=1

def gerar_rd(qtd):
    rds = []
    rd_atual = 1
    n = 0
    while rd_atual <= qtd:
        ref = "RD" + "0" * (6 - len(str(rd_atual))) + str(rd_atual)
        rds.insert(n, ref)
        n += 1
        rd_atual += 1
    return rds

todas = gerar_rd(450)

for i in refs:

    if i in todas:
        todas.remove(i)

print("Referências vazias:")

for i in todas:
    print(i)

local = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, title="Escolha um local para salvar o arquivo")
arq = open(local + "/Referências Vazias.txt", "w")
for i in todas:
    arq.write(i + "\n")
arq.close()
```

It takes specific data from an Excel file to a .txt file. I'm trying to make it executable, so I could run in another computer (also Windows). The last one I tried was Py2exe. This is my **setup.py** file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['rdsvazios.py'])
```

Py2exe generates my .exe but it doesn't work at all.
[This is what I get when I try to execute it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3sa3.png)

What can I do?

P.S.: Python 3.4 / Windows 64 bits

Comment: @rlee827 And where did you see this *readline module*?

Comment: When you executed `python setup.py py2exe` (in your screenshot), it printed out "8 missing modules" along with a list that included `readline`. I think the problem may be with py2exe not being able to include these modules.

Comment: How can I include those modules?